# nginx ingress same host multiple backends

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-helm

I have a service for which i dont want to use autoscaling, so i created a copy of it and now i want to have it behind an internal LB using nginx ingress, one of them will be always active and other one will be passive which can be get through probes status, ingress is as below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: appcj-ingress
spec:  
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: "{{ .Values.ingress.appcjudomain }}"
    http:
      paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: "/"
          backend:
            service:
              name: {{ .Values.Name }}-appcjuengineprihttp
              port:
                number: 81
            service:
              name: {{ .Values.Name }}-appcjuenginesechttp
              port:
                number: 81
```

This is more like a traditional load balancer, like  having multiple servers behind a loadbalancer, having multiple backend services for same host, is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes Ingress does NOT allow you to do this.

You must necessarily distinguish by host or by path.

The only thing you could do is implement a structure like this: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#simple-fanout

Take a look here: [How do I map multiple services to one Kubernetes Ingress path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46373616/how-do-i-map-multiple-services-to-one-kubernetes-ingress-path)

Otherwise consider replacing the Ingress Kubernetes with a level 7 Load Balancer.